# extracting data from span itemprop

Tags: html, vba

I am trying to build a web scraper using vba. I want to extract the address from website but I got stuck.

The html code is

```
<h1 class="agencyname">
 <span item prop="name">
    Text- myname
```

I want to get the output myname in cells(1,1)

I had developed initial code as follows

```
Set obtcoll = ie.document.getElementsBytagname("span")
Cells(1,1).Value = objColl.innerText
```

I am getting the error as **"Object doesn't support this property or method"**

Comment: How did you define `obtcoll`? `Dim outcall as ???`

Comment: I didn't define using dim...just used set obtcoll

Answer (score 0):

It fails because

```
Set obtcoll = ie.document.getElementsBytagname("span")
```

returns a collection. You need to index into this collection to expose the `.innerText` property e.g.

```
Set obtcoll = ie.document.getElementsBytagname("span")(0)
Cells(1,1).Value = objColl.innerText
```

Other than that, the HTML you show does not make it clear where you are obtaining address information from.

You can also do

```
Dim a As Object
Set a = ie.document.querySelectorAll("span[prop=name]")
```

To return a `nodeList` of all `span` elements with a `prop` attribute whose values are `"name"`

For those specific to `agencyname` class use:

```
Dim a As Object
Set a = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".agencyname span[prop=name]")
```